# How to get only part of text from string value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Guys if i have string like that:

```
var tmp1 = " TakeMe ";
```

Is this possible (in some easy way) to get text from that variable, but only "TakeMe"? "TakeMe" is beetwen spaces.

```
var tmp2 = tmp1;  

tmp2 == "TakeMe" not " TakeMe "
```

Well guys you know what i mean. Can someone help me with this? My JS skills are really bad ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you better use regex

```js
var tmp1 = " TakeMe ";

var [text] = tmp1.match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g);
console.log(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```js
var tmp1 = " TakeMe ";

var tmp2 = tmp1.trim();
console.log(tmp2);
```

Comment: It's works but only if i delete unicode icons :D
That's the problem i have icons in that string. I need to ignore them and take text between spaces